YouTube API commentsThreads() displays that a video disabled comments even though the video has tons of comments
While retrieving comments through YouTube API, I have come across a problem in which the code suggests that a video has disabled comments, thus returning an error, even though I can directly access tons of comments through the video's link.
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey= 'MYAPIKEY')


def fetch_comments(video_id):
    response = youtube.videos().list(part="snippet", id = video_id).execute()
    video_title = response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
    print(video_title)

    vid_stats = youtube.videos().list(
        part="statistics",
        id=video_id
    ).execute()

    comment_count = vid_stats.get("items")[0].get("statistics").get("commentCount")
    print(comment_count)
    try:
        comments = []
        response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
            part="snippet",
            videoId=video_id,
            maxResults=100,
            order="relevance",
        ).execute()

        for item in response['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
            print(comment)
            comments.append(comment)

    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An HTTP error occurred: {e}")

video_urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLSUDSNqLgQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAqXDZoa624','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wBgcalM4c4' ]
for url in video_urls:
    print(url)
    video_id = url.split('=')[-1]
    fetch_comments(video_id)

I developed a code to display 4 items: The video's url, video's title, the number of comments, and top 100 comments ordered by relevance, and the code succeeded in its duty except the fourth task: The code suggests that all three videos in the list (video_urls) has "has disabled comments," while you can easily see that all three videos actually have their comments available.



Here's what the output displays:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLSUDSNqLgQ
Everywhere (2017 Remaster)
432
An HTTP error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=wLSUDSNqLgQ&maxResults=100&order=relevance&key=AIzaSyDl-zKEBOx6TAeEZAnX3But1XunhDPOYNA&alt=json returned "The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter has disabled comments.". Details: "[{'message': 'The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter has disabled comments.', 'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 'reason': 'commentsDisabled', 'location': 'videoId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAqXDZoa624
Bette Davis Eyes
2435
An HTTP error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=qAqXDZoa624&maxResults=100&order=relevance&key=AIzaSyDl-zKEBOx6TAeEZAnX3But1XunhDPOYNA&alt=json returned "The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter has disabled comments.". Details: "[{'message': 'The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter has disabled comments.', 'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 'reason': 'commentsDisabled', 'location': 'videoId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wBgcalM4c4
Time After Time
3263

I tried to develop the code to print the total number of  comments to check whether making a reference to the comment itself is disabled, but as it turns out to be successful, I reckon it is the problem to do with the function of the code. Please somebody help me...

Let me know if the Stack Overflow answer 74936220 does not meet your needs.

hello, sorry.
Doesn't seem to work

https://yt.lemnoslife.com/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=wLSUDSNqLgQ&order=relevance works fine on my end, may you precise what doesn't seem to work?

https://youtu.be/qAqXDZoa624?si=ZWD1xmo8kpZCndj5
try this link as example

Currently the official instance is being detected as suspicious, see YouTube-operational-API/issues/11 but it works fine for the video id you just sent if you host your own private instance, see YouTube-operational-API/blob/4557d9aef14a528a805baf474ba5f4ec27de9f03/README.md#install-your-own-instance-of-the-api.
